# EF Recursive Structure

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-sql

I have the following classes

```
public class Person{
   public int Id{get;set};
   public string Name{get;set};
   public int ParentId{get;set};
   public Person Leader{get;set};
   public List<Contribution> Contributions{get;set};

}

public class Contribution{
   public int Id{get;set};
   public string encryptedAmount{get;set};
   public decimal Amount{get;set};
   public int PersonId{get;set};
   public Person Person{get;set};
}
```

I want to be able to get a total for all the contributions made by a person, for a specific leader recursively.

*Note : The Amount on the Contribution is encrypted and can only be decrypted in the application not in SQL*

Should i :

1. Get the Leaders -> People hierarchy using a CTE function in sql and then calling the stored proc from EF. And then after I have all the people, loop through them and get their contributions from the database.
2. Use EF to get the recursive structure + contributions . If the answer is this one, how can achieve this.

Comment: I'd create a view on a CTE showing all `Person` IDs below a `Leader` ID, make this view part of the EF model and join with `Contribution`.

Comment: Would this not allow me to only go one level down. How will I Select from the CTE recursively ?

Comment: The hierarchical query using the CTE should produce records like `1,2`, `1,3`, where `1` is the Leader Id and `2` and `3` are child Person Ids at any level in the hierarchy. So you get all Persons in a Leader's hierarchy by selecting child Id where leader Id = 1.

Comment: I understand that, but I need the whole tree structure after the leader not only the direct reports.

Comment: But that's exactly what a recursive query is capable of, returning the whole tree in a flat table. That's what I meant by saying "at any level in the hierarchy". You could also add a level (or distance, or depth) column to the query.

Comment: Could you maybe give me an example